# about define new visible-sm-table-cell in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 comes with:

- visible-sm-block
- visible-sm-inline
- visible-sm-inline-block

I like to define `visible-sm-table-cell`, like this in my css file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {  
  .visible-sm-table-cell {
      display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

Can I using Less to add this new CSS rule to the Bootstrap compiled css? How? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `custom.less` file in the core bootstrap `/less` folder, then import it in the main `bootstrap.less` file:

```
@import 'custom';
```

Then specify the following in the newly created `custom.less`:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {  
  .visible-sm-table-cell {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

And recompile the files.

PS: I only suggest to create a new `.less` file to avoid modifying the core files for easier possible update in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Nearly all of Bootstrap's mixins are stored in [mixin.less](https://github.com/NateWr/bootstrap3/blob/master/bootstrap/less/mixins.less), described as a wonderful utility. You can edit it to add your `custom.less` file or edit the `bootstrap.less` file. Our team forked the project and modified `mixin.less` for our own custimized project. (It is only our choice). We added :

`@import 'custom';`

`.less` file enables you to use a mixin in any of the `.less` files in the toolkit.

`$ lessc ./less/bootstrap.less > myBootstrap.css`

Less could be used until version 2 (I'm not sure). But now Bootstrap is using [Grunt](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt) to compile less files.

As you can see in [variables.less](https://github.com/NateWr/bootstrap3/blob/master/bootstrap/less/variables.less) file 768 is `@screen-sm-min` and 991 is `@screen-sm-max`. So your `custom.less` file could be :

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {  
    .visible-sm-table-cell {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
```